# Programmatically adding Chart into a Program but not showing the chart output

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I am creating chart dynamically and connect it with database table to show the chart output but my chart data source couldn't get the database table or I don't know why getting no output. What is the problem in data source or data-binding? to show charts

```
Chart addchart()
{
    Chart chartA = new Chart();
    SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=D:\Task_2\Task_2\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
    cs.Open();
    SqlCommand md=new SqlCommand("Select*from Agestatistics",cs);
    md.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cs.Close();
    try
    {
        Legend legend = new Legend();
        chartA.BackColor = Color.White;
        chartA.Location =new Point(t,l);
        chartA.Width = 370;
        chartA.Height = 250;
        chartA.Name = ""+x;
        chartA.Legends.Add(legend);
        legend.TitleFont = new Font(legend.Font.FontFamily, 7);
        //legend.Font = new Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Bold);
        legend.Title = "Age of the Employees";
        Series series;
        series = new Series(""+x );
        series[""+x] = "Disabled";
        series.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
        series.LabelAngle = 0;
        series.Font = new Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Bold);
        // series.SmartLabelStyle.Enabled = true;
        series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie;
        series.LegendToolTip = ("Age of The Employees");
        series.IsVisibleInLegend = true;
        chartA.Series.Add(series);
        ChartArea chartArea = new ChartArea();
        Axis yAxis = new Axis(chartArea, AxisName.Y);
        Axis xAxis = new Axis(chartArea, AxisName.X);
        chartA.Series["" + x].XValueMember = "" + x;
        chartA.Series["" + x].YValueMembers = "" + y;
        chartArea.AxisX.Title = "Age";
        chartArea.AxisY.Title = "Total";
        chartA.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea);
        chartA.Legends[0].ForeColor = Color.Blue;
        chartA.Series["" + x].LabelForeColor=Color.DarkGreen;
        chartA.Titles.Add("Age Statistics of The Employees");
        chartA.DataSource = md;                        
        chartA.DataBind();                        
        chartA.Show();
        control.Controls.Add(chartA);
        chartA.Show();                     
    }
    catch
    {
         MessageBox.Show("Connection Problem", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    return chartA;
}
```

Comment: Not sure what other errors there is, but just looking at it Select*from Agestatistics should have some spaces: Select * from Agestatistics

Comment: Put a break point and check you data after the comand.

Comment: I think the issue is in the dara binding. For testing remove that and add a few points in code. - If that works then try to correct the binding. - There are [many ways](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd456766%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to bind data to a chart. One big difference to binding e.g.  a DataGridview is that a Chart by default will only bind __two__ values and __you should tell it which__. You best bind to a `Series.Points`not the chart itself and set the valuemembers! Do look at the many [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3152130+chart+databinding) around!!

Comment: You're trying to bind the Chart to a SqlCommand. [SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery)

Comment: Sir! the problem is what command ChartA.DataSource=cmd //SelectCommand. Not working. Mean Not getting data no output coming and no error in the code.

Comment: That's not the way to create and set a DataSource. Use a [SqlDataAdapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter) to `.Fill()` a DataSet or a DataTable.